# Will the Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll be able to be used with sqlite3.dll for WinRT?

Tags: database, sqlite, mono, windows-runtime

Will the Mono.Data.Sqlite library be implementing the DbConnection/SqliteConnection and DbCommand/SqliteCommand for the upcoming release of the sqlite3's support for the WinRT build?

I know (or at least can't find any references) that the Metro/WinRT does not contain the System.Data.Common namespace.

I am developing a cross-platform app that uses a sqlite database and would like to have a total re-use of the database layer at least. Also, CSharp-Sqlite does not have all the features of sqlite yet.

I know that the csharp-sqlite library currently supports WinRT, but it would be nice to rely on fewer entities in development. I am currently going to have to rely on Xamarin/Mono for Desktop/iOS/Android and CSharp-Sqlite for WinRT/WP/Silverlight. **If sqlite3.dll was going to natively support WinRT then Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll could as well?**

**Maybe after the WinRT support for sqlite3, the guys could find their way to supporting Silverlight and Windows Phone?** :)

Any takers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This doesn't answer your question, but might address your problem.*

The [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) by Tim Heuer about SQLite support on WinRT states:

> Some may ask about System.Data.Sqlite and this cannot be used because of the dependency of ADO.NET which is not a part of the .NET Framework Core profile.

So although a native SQLite binary can now be used in WinRT Metro style applications, the managed ADO-NET driver (System.Data.SQLite) is not supported. Tim suggests using the lightweight [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) C# wrapper, which is a thin ORM wrapper over P/Invoke access to the native SQLite library. sqlite-net certainly works on Mono, including MonoTouch and Mono for Android.

Windows Phone and Silverlight before version 5 is a different issue - generally native code is not supported, but sqlite-net also works with the purely managed [csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) implementation, so that keeps you to a single front-end library, with a different back-end on these platforms.

Comment: Thanks for this. I know csharp-sqlite uses a dummy System.Data.Common namespace from the System.Data.Ersatz library. Will Mono.Data.Sqlite ever do something like this? I am actually working on a similar library, but I opted to use the Mono.Data.Sqlite provided SqliteCommand and SqliteConnection implementations instead of re-implementing them.

Comment: This does make the requirements a little larger, but I feel the benefits outweigh the cost - for example there is an issue https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/67 : BeginTransaction/Commit cannot be nested. This issue does not occur when using the Mono.Data.Sqlite implementation of SqliteConnection.

Comment: This is a small thing, but it does help reduce the maintenance required, as the core library is maintained be sqlite, the .NET wrapper by Mono and all I have to worry about is the ORM.

Comment: My library is : https://github.com/mattleibow/Mono.Data.Sqlite.Orm - It is heavily based on sqlite-net, but I feel that there are more features and does not have as many #ifs as that lib.